# What should we do to questions asked by user and not responded

Tags: discussion, questions, ethics

I can see that many people ask question and then when they recieve some response they never come back. What should we do to such questions? Should we put time frame to ask user to respond to post or else question should be deleted and point should be awarded to one who responded to user.

Comment: How do you define a user response programmatically?

Comment: Hmmm thats pretty difficult. Cant we check for questions where user has not accepted any answer or given +1 point to responder?

Comment: @AshReva: what if none of the answers so far work? (You'd be forcing the asker to upvote a poor answer just to avoid his question getting deleted).

Comment: i agree with you David Robinson.

Comment: Feature request is when you are requesting for some new feature; this here is a pure discussion.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't bother mods with it.  It isn't our job to judge when a question should be closed for inactivity.  That kind of decision should be a joint one among members of the community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question is likely to help more than just the OP, nothing should be done. Other users will be helped by question and its answers, and its likely that some will upvote the answers up eventually, thus rewarding the answerers.

Its also possible that the user decides to rejoin the site months, or even years later, and will likely go back through their questions and accept an answer to improve their Accept Rate. I've had some of my answers get accepted months after I've posted them, so it's not that uncommon.

But if it's likely that the answer will *only* help the OP, such as the problem being a typo in the OP's code, then it should be closed as too-localized.

Comment: In the latter case, does it matter whether the OP has responded or not?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really anything special to do.  If the question as it stands meets the conditions for closure, close it (often this is because there is not enough information provided to answer the question).  If it meets the conditions for deletion, delete it.  If it doesn't, don't.  If you want to downvote the OP for not following up, that's entirely up to you, you can vote how you want.

The fact that someone isn't following up is not, in and of itself, justification for closing or deleting a question.